# Concatenation of two template variables to take as input in angular

Tags: angular, concatenation, angular2-directives, ngmodel

I have two input tags with two template reference variables attached to them in my template file. I have a variable in my typescript file to which I want to assign the concatenation of both these inputs. Is there any way of doing this for example modifying what the ngModel directive assigns to variables? For the record, I'm looking for a way to directly assign the concatenated versions of these input instead of assigning them to separate variables in typescript and then concatenating them there.

The template:

```
<div><input #key type = "text"><input #value type = "text"></div>
```

The typescript file:

```
'keyValueConcatenation: string = "";'
```

Desired assignment:
`keyValueConcatenation  = key.value+value.value`

Comment: please provide a little bit more information and show us what have u tried so far.

Comment: I've edited the post @FarhatZaman

Comment: Let me know what other details you require